# error from linq while execting stored procedure from linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I need to execute SQL Server stored procedure from linq-to-sql. I added my stored procedure in data context and used the context in my class. Here is my code to call sql server stored procedure from c# class:

```
using (DBTestDataContext db = new DBTestDataContext())
{

     db.myStoreProcedure(name, address, hasValue); 
}
```

Here, hasValue is of bit type, name and address are of string type and i have pass value in hasValue as true/false making it a bool type. My issue is as the procedure is executed, I am getting the error

```
Could not translate expression 'value (DBTestDataContext.myStoreProcedure("abc","xyz",true)) into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.
```

However, it executed successfully in sql server:

```
EXEC dbo.myStoreProcedure @name="abc", @address = "xyz", @hasValue = true
```

it is working fine. Is this the issue associated with db.myStoreProcedure ??? For any data entered, this code is not working. How can it be fixed

Can anyone help me how to fix this. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it like this .

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", 1);
var param2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", 2);

var  results = context.Database.SqlQuery<StronglyTypedObject>
               ("SPName @param1, @param2",param1, param2).ToList()
```

Comment: `StronglyTypedObject` properties must match the fields returned from the SP in order to bind correctly